# Is there anyway to escape strings consistently in Google Earth kml files?

Tags: kml, google-earth

When creating kml content for Google Earth, I noticed a discrepancy in how it tries to escape characters to prevent JavaScript code execution.  If characters inside `<name></name>` tags are escaped twice to their HTML character codes e.g. "`<script></script>`" to `&#38;#60;script&#38;#62;&#38;#60;/script&#38;#62;` then it will display correctly as `<script></script>` in the side bar, but in the label for the placemarker, it will display as `&#60;script&#62;&#60;/script&#62;`.  It would be preferable that the text was escaped so that it would display exactly the same in both places.

Examples files and their Google Earth representations have been added to this post.

The first image shows a string that has been unescaped and you can see that in the sidebar cuts off some text in the  tag but displays the entire tag correctly in the main window.  You can also see that some JavaScript in the  tag has been executed in the  window.  The attached file unescaped.kml is the file opened in this screen shot.

[Link to first image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PkFmG.jpg)

KML file used:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!--The name of the placemark is escaped properly on the label of the pushpin but not in the sidebar (Does not validate with KML Validator)-->
<kml xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2" xmlns:gx="http://www.google.com/kml/ext/2.2">
  <Placemark>
    <name>&#60;script&#62;document.write("TEST")&#60;/script&#62; Text</name>
    <description>Text</description>
    <Point>
      <coordinates>10,10,0 </coordinates>
    </Point>
  </Placemark>
</kml>
```

The second image shows the same string escaped properly to avoid JavaScript execution, but it does not parse the html character codes correctly on the placemark label in the main window.  The attached file escaped.kml is the file opened in this screen shot.

[Link to second image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T8EcX.jpg)

KML File used:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!--The name of the placemark is escaped properly on the label of the pushpin but not in the sidebar (Does not validate with KML Validator)-->
<kml xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2" xmlns:gx="http://www.google.com/kml/ext/2.2">
  <Placemark>
    <name>&#38;#60;script&#38;#62;document.write("TEST")&#38;#60;/script&#38;#62; Text</name>
      <description>Text</description>
      <Point>
        <coordinates>10,10,0 </coordinates>
      </Point>
  </Placemark>
</kml>
```

Is there a workaround that correctly escapes the text and correctly escapes the strings properly and displays them correctly or is this just a bug in Google Earth that I have to deal with?

Comment: Try CDATA http://www.quackit.com/xml/tutorial/xml_cdata.cfm

Comment: I did try using a CDATA block.  The only difference is that instead of escaping strings twice, I only have to escape strings once, but other than that, Google Earth will still display the name exactly the same as in the second linked image.